# scala foreach of a 2-D List/Array in chisel with types issue

Tags: scala, foreach, chisel

Can "foreach" can be used for each element of the 2-D List/Array?
I tried the code:

```
val n_vec = (0 to 2).map(i=>
              (0 to 2).map(j=>
                Wire(UInt(3.W))
              )
            ) 
n_vec.foreach((i:Int)=>(
  n_vec(i).foreach((j:Int)=>{
    n_vec(i)(j) := i.U + j.U
  })
))
```

the error message is

```
top.scala:24: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int => Unit
 required: chisel3.core.UInt => ?
      n_vec(i).foreach((j:Int)=>{
                              ^
```

Could you enlight me whether it can be used in such a way, even how?

Comment: It looks like your code is expecting a type of `UInt`, but the return type of a `foreach` will always be a `Unit`, trying changing `foreach` to `map`

Comment: @Tyler yeah, I know `map` can do it. but somehow it cost much more memory for returning array/list, also I know `for` body can do it. I just wonder about `foreach` to lead me to learn into it.

Comment: @Tyler The problem is argument type, not return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be cleaner to write like this:

```
n_vec.foreach { i=>
  i.foreach { j=>
    j := x.U + y.U
    y = y + 1
  }
  y = 0
  x = x + 1
}
```

But you don't need to increment `x` and `y` manually, just iterate over indices instead:

```
n_vec.indices.foreach { x =>
  n_vec(x).indices.foreach { y =>
    n_vec(x)(y) := x.U + y.U
  }
}
```

or better (and this translates exactly to the above)

```
for { 
  x <- n_vec.indices
  y <- n_vec(x).indices
} {
  n_vec(x)(y) := x.U + y.U
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be used this way.

solution:

```
var x = 0
var y = 0 
n_vec.foreach(i=>{
  i.foreach(j=>{
    j := x.U + y.U
    y = y + 1
  })
  y = 0
  x = x + 1
})
x = 0
y = 0
```